# Get name of elements of a OrderedDict in pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ordereddictionary

I am importing a excel file which have several sheets. I am using the next line of code to do that:

```
books = pd.read_excel('books2.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

'books' now is a OrderedDict.

The question is: how can I get the name of the sheets as a list?

Comment: Have you tried `list(books)`?

Comment: OMG! That was fast and effective. Thanks.